# 2 ways to calculate profits, which both seem legit, but produce different results - what am I missing?

Tags: equities, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to calculate this simple example with 2 ways which both seem legit, and getting different results.

Way 1: at the beginning of day $t$, first reset the holdings to 0, then buy the number of holdings you should buy (given a signal).

Way 2: at the beginning of day $t$, calculate the profits given the holdings and today's price, then adjust the holdings to today's signal.

I assume lab conditions: zero transaction costs, no friction, etc.

I will now show an example, together with detailed explanation:
Consider pricing `p=[0,1,2,1,0]`; and signals `s=[0,1,2,1,0]`, that is: 'we should hold the same amount of stocks as the stock's price'.

Way 1:

> Started at day 0 with 0 stocks.
>
> Beginning of t=1. current price: 1, current holding rule: 1
>
> Flattening to 0 stocks:       will sell 0 stock(s) for price 1 each. action
>   total: +0, cumulative total: +0.0
>
> Should hold 1 stock(s):   will buy 1 stock(s) for price 1 each. action
>   total: -1, cumulative total: -1.0
>
> Beginning of t=2. current price: 2, current holding rule: 2
>
> Flattening to 0 stocks:       will sell 1 stock(s) for price 2 each. action
>   total: +2, cumulative total: +1.0
>
> Should hold 2 stock(s):   will buy 2 stock(s) for price 2 each. action
>   total: -4, cumulative total: -3.0
>
> Beginning of t=3. current price: 1, current holding rule: 1
>
> Flattening to 0 stocks:       will sell 2 stock(s) for price 1 each. action
>   total: +2, cumulative total: -1.0
>
> Should hold 1 stock(s):   will buy 1 stock(s) for price 1 each. action
>   total: -1, cumulative total: -2.0
>
> Beginning of t=4. current price: 0, current holding rule: 0
>
> Flattening to 0 stocks:       will sell 1 stock(s) for price 0 each. action
>   total: +0, cumulative total: -2.0
>
> Should hold 0 stock(s):   will buy 0 stock(s) for price 0 each. action
>   total: +0, cumulative total: -2.0

So, in total, we lose -2.0 money using way 1.

Now, consider way 2 with same settings:

> Started at day 0 with 0 stocks.
>
> Beginning of t=1. current price: 1, current holding rule: 1
>
> Calculating profits: currently holding 0 stock(s), and price went
>   0->1. action total: +0, cumulative total: +0.0
>
> Will rebalance to hold 0->1 stocks for price 1 each. action total: -1,
>   cumulative total: -1.0
>
> Beginning of t=2. current price: 2, current holding rule: 2
>
> Calculating profits: currently holding 1 stock(s), and price went
>   1->2. action total: +1, cumulative total: +0.0
>
> Will rebalance to hold 1->2 stocks for price 2 each. action total: -2,
>   cumulative total: -2.0
>
> Beginning of t=3. current price: 1, current holding rule: 1
>
> Calculating profits: currently holding 2 stock(s), and price went
>   2->1. action total: -2, cumulative total: -4.0
>
> Will rebalance to hold 2->1 stocks for price 1 each. action total: +1,
>   cumulative total: -3.0
>
> Beginning of t=4. current price: 0, current holding rule: 0
>
> Calculating profits: currently holding 1 stock(s), and price went
>   1->0. action total: -1, cumulative total: -4.0
>
> Will rebalance to hold 1->0 stocks for price 0 each. action total: +0,
>   cumulative total: -4.0

Here, we lose 4.0 money.

Both ways seem OK when I try to find 'bugs' but since I get different results, there certainly must be something I miss. What is it?

Comment: FWIW I did the calculations my way, and I find that Method 1 gives the right answer: the overall P&L is -2. I have not looked yet at method 2 long enough to understand what is wrong ...

Comment: In Method 2, what does cumulative_total represent? It seems to be a mixture of apples and oranges which combine the cost of buying/selling stocks with the incremental P&l of each day.

Comment: @AlexC Thanks. Regarding Method 2, I see it as a process of expanses and incomes. For example: In day 1, we buy 1 stock at price 1, so we are -1. Then, at the end of the day (which is the beginning of day 2), the stock rises, and now worth 2, so we actually made $1 while still holding the stock, and so on... hope I made it clear as much as possible. Maybe that's what I miss

Comment: Method 2 isn’t internally consistent. You are counting your results based on cash flows but then at t=2 and later you count unrealised pnl (stock goes up or down) as a cash flow which it isn’t. In that case step two part one is not a gain of 1 but a cash flow of 0 and the cumulative cash flow is -3 at end of step 2 once you bought the second share for 2. In step 3 the stock move itself generates nothing again, but the rebalancing is a +1 (selling a share at 1), cumulative -2. At step 4 your remaining stock has gone to 0 and selling it is +0, cumulative -2.

Comment: Thank you, @Ivan for your comment. That makes sense.